# NestedError: topic/partition change check failed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-topic

Suddenly I got an issue in running process of apache kafka consumer group.
Anyone please share your thoughts on why this issue happens.

```
  NestedError: topic/partition change check failed
      at _checkTopicPartitionChange (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroup.js:295:37)
      at client.loadMetadataForTopics (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroup.js:323:14)
      at async.series (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:919:7)
      at <system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3888:9
      at <system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
      at iterateeCallback (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:988:17)
      at <system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:16
      at <system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3885:13
      at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:491:5)
      at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
      at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
      at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  Caused By: TimeoutError: Request timed out after 30000ms
      at new TimeoutError (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/errors/TimeoutError.js:6:9)
      at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (<system-path>/node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js:491:14)
      at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
      at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
      at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  (node:12516) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
```

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Check is one of the brokers went down around that time?

Comment: No, each brokers running well